# Why pygame error video system not initialzed, even though I only use key module?

Tags: python, pygame

```
from pygame import key
keys = key.get_pressed()
```

I'm running this on Debian 10, Python 3.7.3, pygame 2.0.1.

- Edit 1:
  I assume that using only the "key" module does not require `pygame.init()` because there is not `pygame.key.init()` method, but some other modules like "mixer" does. Having `pygame.init()` in the script still results in the same error, with an additional error before that: "error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment."

@furas also pointed out that I need to define a window for pygame to work, but I'm building a headless system with no GUI so I want to avoid unnecessary memory consumption. Is there a workaround that allows me to use the pygame key module to detect keyboard input without having to create a window?

Comment: Could you please share what makes you think that using only the key module doesn't require the initialisation?

Comment: system (Windows, Linux, MacOS) sends keys/mouse events only to active window - so you have to create window in PyGame to get key/mouse events. If you want to get keys without window then you should use module like `keyboard` or `pynput`.

Comment: @Pac0 for submodules like "mixer" they provide `init()` method, while the "key" module does not, so I think `pygame.init()` will only call the `init()` methods available in the submodules.

Comment: @furas thanks, I want to try out this module because the APIs seem easy to implement. I will try `pynput` next, as `keyboard` seems to require root privilege.

Comment: @PhucMai Thanks, your rationale makes sense. But you don't get the error anymore, if you call `pygame.init()`, right?

Comment: `pygame.init()` removes error but it will still not gives keys - you would have to create window and make it active (focused) and then system will send keys/mouse event to this window and you can get it in code. But you would have to also run loop with `pygame.event.get()` to update data in table which you get with `get_pressed()`

Comment: @Pac0 with `pygame.init()` I actually still have the same error, additionally also this error "error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.", but that makes sense because I'm building a headless system and it is missing a lot of libraries. I do wish to save memory and processing capability, so I will not create a window with pygame.

Comment: these are relevant details for your problem, making it different from the duplicate target. Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67878805/edit) your question and include them? I'll gladly vote for reopening it.

Comment: @Pac0 thanks, I just added those info in the main question.